# Array isn't sorting when writing to file

Tags: php, file, sorting, text, implode

I wrote this script:

```
<?PHP
$file_handle = fopen("info.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts[] = explode('|', $line_of_text);
}

fclose($file_handle);
$a = $parts;

function cmp($a,$b){
    return strtotime($a[8])<strtotime($b[8])?1:-1;
};

uasort($a, 'cmp');
$failas = "dinfo.txt";
$fh = fopen($failas, 'w');

for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
    $txt=implode('|', $a[$i]);
    fwrite($fh, $txt);
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

When I use:

```
print_r($a);
```

after

```
uasort($a, 'cmp');
```

Then I can see sorted array. But when I write to file using these commands:

```
$fh=fopen($failas, 'w');
for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
    $txt=implode('|', $a[$i]);
    fwrite($fh, $txt);
}
fclose($fh);
```

It shows not sorted information, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I first get your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) where every line is one array element. There I ignore empty lines and new line characters at the end of each line.

After this I sort the array with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). Where I first get all dates and times from each line by [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)'ing it. After this I simply get the timestamp of each date with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and compare it which each other.

At the end I simply save the file with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), where I also add a new line character at the end of each line with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    usort($lines, function($a, $b){
        list($aDate, $aTime) = explode(" ", explode("|", $a)[substr_count($a, "|")]);
        list($bDate, $bTime) = explode(" ", explode("|", $b)[substr_count($b, "|")]);

        if(strtotime("$aDate $aTime") == strtotime("$bDate $bTime"))
            return 0;
        return strtotime("$aDate $aTime") < strtotime("$bDate $bTime") ? 1 : -1;
    });

    file_put_contents("test.txt", array_map(function($v){return $v . PHP_EOL;}, $lines));

?>
```

**Side notes:**

I would recommend you to save this data in a database where it is much flexible to sort and getting the data!

**EDIT:**

For people which have a php version (`echo phpversion();`) under <5.3, just change the anonymous functions to normal functions and pass the function name as strings like this:

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    function timestampCmp($a, $b) {
        $aExploded = explode("|", $a);
        $bExploded = explode("|", $b);

        list($aDate, $aTime) = explode(" ", $aExploded[substr_count($a, "|")]);
        list($bDate, $bTime) = explode(" ", $bExploded[substr_count($b, "|")]);

        if(strtotime("$aDate $aTime") == strtotime("$bDate $bTime"))
            return 0;
        return strtotime("$aDate $aTime") < strtotime("$bDate $bTime") ? 1 : -1;

    }

    function addEndLine($v) {
        return $v . PHP_EOL;
    }

    usort($lines, "timestampCmp");

    file_put_contents("test.txt", array_map("addEndLine", $lines));

?>
```

Comment: i get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in ...... on line 5

Comment: @Albance You're welcome! Have a nice day! (BTW: For next time include your code from the start!)